# Dismiss modal on Apple Watch

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I am trying to make a simple transition between 2 interface controllers as below.

The transition from FirstInterfaceController to SecondInterfaceController works, but I cannot close the modal by [self dismissContoller]. Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

In FirstInterfaceController

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"SecondIC" context:nil];
```

In SecondInterfaceController

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction {
    [self dismissController];
}
```

I know that you can go back by tapping the button on the upper left corner, but I want to place a button to close modal explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the -[popController] instead.